# Material UI : How to extract the value of the text field

Tags: reactjs, authentication, frontend, material-ui, textfield

How can I get the user value in the text field component.

This is the form text field value I want to populate. I am using material ui and tried using hooks and useEffect to get the desired results.

```
<TextField
             variant="outlined"
             margin="normal"
             required
             fullWidth
             name="password"
             label="Password"
             type="password"
             id="password"
             autoComplete="current-password"
             autoFocus
           />
<FormControlLabel
             control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
             label="Remember me"
           />
           <Button
             type="submit"
             fullWidth
             variant="contained"
             color="primary"
             className={classes.submit}
             onClick={handleClick}
           >
             Sign In
           </Button>
</form>



How can I get the password in alert/console log on handleClick. 

const handleClick = () => {
   console.log(password);
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use State. 
Whenever the value of the TextField change, you save the value in the component state.
When you click submit, you have access to the state:

```
const TextFieldWithState = () => {
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(password);
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <TextField
        variant="outlined"
        margin="normal"
        required
        fullWidth
        name="password"
        label="Password"
        type="password"
        id="password"
        autoComplete="current-password"
        autoFocus
        value={password}
        onChange={(event) => {setPassword(event.target.value)}} //whenever the text field change, you save the value in state
       />
      <FormControlLabel
        control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
        label="Remember me"
      />
      <Button
        type="submit"
        fullWidth
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
      //  className={classes.submit}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Sign In
      </Button>
  </form>
  );
};
```

You can learn more about useState hook [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Comment: How can I pass the value of password to other components ?@Ido Thanks

Comment: There are multiple ways. is 'other component' is a parent or sibling of the component in the question?

Comment: the details of the password needs to be transferred to a different page, handled using routing on handleClick method. So the password value needs to be sent to /view page. Thanks

````const handleClick = () => {
    history.push("/view");
  }; ````

Comment: In this case, you should use Redux library. It's a little difficult to catch at start- but it will pay off. It's a great way to share state between pages in your app. To get started, go through the [Basic Tutorial](https://redux.js.org/basics/basic-tutorial)

Comment: You can also [Lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to the first common ancestor of the two components (probably the component that renders <Route>). This is highly not recommended, beacuse as your app grows you will get into callback hell.